# Dajaxice performance measures for high-traffic site

Tags: python, django, performance, jquery, dajaxice

If this question has already been answered by someone on this site, please point me there.

Is it a good option to use Dajaxice for a high-traffic website, assuming millions of hits per day? Has anybody faced performance issues in terms of load-times for web pages with multiple AJAX calls to server?

What are the alternatives for Python+Django projects? Is it better to use just jQuery?

Comment: My nginx cache is 10-20x faster and can handle tens to hundreds of times the concurrent requests vs my app. So ultimately, it doesn't even have to do with the web app but my cache which is platform agnostic. Unless the data is so dynamic that it can't be cached as reliably.

Comment: @YujiTomita So and what you caching with your nginx frontend, static files?

Comment: @denis, oops, what I mean is that my nginx pulls cached pages from memcached. If it misses, my app generates one. Since my highest traffic ajax / traffic is okay to cache every 5-10 minutes - my app performance is about memcached + nginx, not my app.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the main load in the web application laying on databases. Not on frameworks or templates engines.